# What should I do to launch the telepresence daemon process in macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, launchd, daemons

When I use the following command to check telepresence status in macOS 12.5 with M1 pro chip,

```
telepresence status
```

I get the error:

```
telepresence: error: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix /var/run/telepresence-daemon.socket: connect: connection refused" (socket rm failed with remove /var/run/telepresence-daemon.socket: permission denied); this usually means that the process has terminated ungracefully

See logs for details (2 errors found): "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Logs/telepresence/daemon.log"

See logs for details (1 error found): "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Logs/telepresence/connector.log"
If you think you have encountered a bug, please run `telepresence gather-logs` and attach the telepresence_logs.zip to your github issue or create a new one: https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md .
```

Then I try to start the daemon process with:

```
launchctl start telepresence
```

but nothing happens. Then I try to search for the daemon process files with:

```
launchctl list|grep telepresence
```

but I get no response. What should I do to start the daemon process?

Comment: Considering the error message complains that a file already exists, I would imagine removing that file would fix it...